# Django Models Field.E340 : ManytoMany relationship same intermediate table name in 2 different apps

Tags: python, django

We are trying to makemigrations and migrating the app level model to respective databases using database router.

We have one model file in one app pointing to one database and same structured models with table name with some tables added are being created in other app then intermediate table name is creating error.

Error : master.LegalTbl.legal_field_name: (field.E340) The field's intermediary table 'tbl_legal_tbl' clashes with the table name of 'user.LegalTbl'.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure may be it could work:

- delete the migration file that has conflict.
- add Class Meta to your model which name you want to change
- meta class have one attribute called db_table write table name

Now you can run makemigrations and migrate, it will solve your conflict i guess

Comment: No migration File created

Comment: Then simply follow from step 2

Comment: Change the db_table with any other name like "table_user_legal" or "user_table_extra" something like that